# cssclass not working for checkboxlist

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, checkboxlist

There is a checkboxlist for which I want to display border of each checkbox item. As per my knowledge it will work on setting up td cssclass as checkboxlist save items in td. I tried below code but its not working.

aspx code

```css
<style type="text/css">
     .chkboxlist td
     {
         font-size: large;
         background-color: Green;
         border-color: Red;
         color: black;
     }
</style>
```

```html
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkCompanies" RepeatDirection="Vertical" CellSpacing="5" CellPadding="5"                                          runat="server" CssClass="chkboxlist"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

aspx.cs code

```
chkCompanies.DataSource = dtCompanyList;
            chkCompanies.DataTextField = "Emp_Company";
            chkCompanies.DataBind();
```

CSSClass is in head section of aspx code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"As per my knowledge it will work on setting up td cssclass as checkboxlist save items in td"* - That is incorrect.

When you specify `.chkboxlist td` as the CSS selector, you are not targeting your `asp:CheckBoxList` element, because it's **not** a `<td>` element.

Remove the `td` selector and it should work fine:

```
<style type="text/css">
      .chkboxlist
      {
          font-size: large;
          background-color: Green;
          border-color: Red;
          color: black;
      }
</style>
```

If you want to change **each** `CheckBox` border, you can set it in code-behind, in the `OnDataBound` event:

```
foreach (ListItem li in chkCompanies.Items)
{
    li.Attributes.Add("Style", "border: solid 1px black;");
}
```